# Hiding DataGridView Row 0 produces error

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, currencymanager

In my DataGridView, it fails to hide a row, if that row is index 0.

> row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made
>   invisible

```
Dim cm1 As CurrencyManager = CType(BindingContext(dgv.DataSource), CurrencyManager)
cm1.SuspendBinding()
dgv.Rows.Item(0).Visible = False 'this throws the exception
```

Comment: Isnt there a property to supress row errors?

Comment: I could pretty easily put a try/catch inside the for loop, but thats just ignoring the problem :-P

Comment: I was going off the title...

Comment: ah crap, that is pretty misleading, sorry.

Comment: That's OK, thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding I believe if that's the only row left and it's selected the row or cell must be visible. To get around this you could possibly setting the current cell to null then `SuspendBinding`...

Here's a simple example...

```
 Me.dgv.CurrentCell = Nothing
 Me.cm1.SuspendBinding()
 Me.dgv.Rows(index).Visible = False
```

Comment: why making current cell to null?